# Linked List "exception thrown"

Tags: c++, oop, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm working on this Linked list program for school and when i tried to run my program i got this message that says "Exception thrown:read access violation, student was nullptr". here is my main function were "student" is found

```
int main() {
    ifstream datafile;
    list studentinfo;
    list::node *student = NULL;
    list::nodePtr head = NULL;
    list::node nodeinfo[10];

    datafile.open("Z:\\CS246\\Linked_List_Final\\studentdata.txt");
    if (!datafile)
    {
        cout << "Error!!";
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        datafile >> nodeinfo[i].name >> nodeinfo[i].id >> nodeinfo[i].gpa;
        studentinfo.addNode(&student, student->id);
    }
    list displayList(studentinfo);

    string choice, ans;
    int pos;

    cout << "Would you like to delete a node? If so type yes:";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == "yes" || choice == "Yes") {
        do {
            cout << "Type the postion of the node you would like to delete";
            cin >> pos;
            studentinfo.deleteNode(pos);
            cout << "Is there another node you would like to delete?";
            cin >> ans;
        } while (ans == "yes" || ans == "Yes");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Please let me know if i need to post the rest of my code.

Comment: The only place student is used in that code is `studentinfo.addNode(&student, student->id);` so it must be in that function? But is suggest you try running your code under a debugger which will show you the exact line where the problem occurred

Comment: It looks like somewhere you have a `list` class. This class should be doing all of the management of nodes. `main` is better off is it knows nothing of `list::node`, `head` or `list::nodePtr`. All `main` should know about and have an instance of is `list` See the section of your textbook on encapsulation for details on why.

Comment: i got this error from the debugger lol

Comment: @JoshuaMckinney Then you should add to your question at which line the debugger indicated the error and what you have done so far in your debugging session to determine the cause of the problem, so that others don't have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
    studentinfo.addNode(&student, student->id);
```

In here, you try to dereference `student`, even though its value is nullptr. Before doing so, you need to assign some value to it. Maybe you were looking for `nodeinfo[i].id` instead?

Comment: thanks i tried ```student = nodeinfo;``` and it worked, but now the file wont open

Answer (score 1):

```
studentinfo.addNode(&student, student->id);
```

Is it so that at this point *student* is not instanciated when you try to access it (->)? nullptr cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

You set student pointer to null and then try to access student->id but it only has the value of null.

Comment: i kept getting errors when i had it set to ```List::node *student;```

Answer (score 0):

```
List::node * student = NULL;
...
student->id
```

Null dereference.

Comment: how should i do that?

Comment: @JoshuaMckinney I'm telling you what you are doing wrong. You cannot dereference `NULL`. Also, in your code, why do you have a "linked list", but also make an `array` of nodes? You need to pick which one you want.